# How do i write this require as an es6 import statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, ecmascript-6

## Problem

I have this require statement

```
require('smoothscroll-polyfill').polyfill();
```

But I would like to write it as an es6 import statement

I have tried

```
import 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
```

and

```
import * as 'smoothscrollPolyfill' from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
```

But cant get it to work correctly, so what is the correct way to import a package like this?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without seeing the exports in the module you're importing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd do it in two parts, first the import, then the function call:

If `polyfill` itself is a named export **and** it doesn't care what `this` is when it's called:

```
import {polyfill} from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
polyfill();
```

*(And you've now [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579853/how-do-i-write-this-require-as-an-es6-import-statement/42579961?noredirect=1#comment72292602_42579961) that was the case.)*

---

For completeness, before the above was confirmed, I also listed these other possibilities which may be useful for others in future:

If `polyfill` is a property on the *default* export (rather than its own named export), then we import the default (no `{}` in the `import` statement) and then use its property:

```
import smoothScrollPolyFill from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
const polyfill = smoothScrollPolyFill.polyfill();
```

If the `smoothScrollPolyFill` part is a *named* export and `polyfill` is a property on it, then we'd use the `{}` on `import`:

```
import {smoothScrollPolyFill} from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';
const polyfill = smoothScrollPolyFill.polyfill();
```

Comment: `import {polyfill} from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';` worked like a charm. Thanks for the explanation aswell.

Comment: @JoeLloyd: Glad that helped.

Answer (score 4):

using `import {} from '...'` instead.

```
 import {polyfill} from 'smoothscroll-polyfill';//ref polyfill from 'smotthscroll-polyfill'
 polyfill();//ref a method,so you must call it after imported.
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Babel or something similar to provide compatibility between CommonJS modules and ES6 modules, the syntax would look something like this:

```
import smoothscrollPolyfill from "smoothscroll-polyfill";
smoothscrollPolyfill.polyfill();
```