# Import ES6 modules with properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mailgun

I am using ES6 on the server with NodeJS. I use babel to transpile it and everything works correctly, but I have a problem where I do not know how to proceed. I need to be able to write this fragment of code ES5 in code ES6, I would appreciate someone explaining how to do it and why it does not work what I am doing.

In particular, I need to make this code in ES5, run in ES6:

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
  apiKey: config.mail.api.api_key,
  domain: config.mail.api.domain
})
```

Currently, I am trying to use the following code, but it does not work:

```
import mailgun from 'mailgun-js'
mailgun = {
  apiKey: config.mail.api.api_key,
  domain: config.mail.api.domain
}
```

The configuration parameters have a config.js file which works correctly.
When transpiling the code, the console returns me the following error message in the log:

[Log Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXrBY.png)

I need to know what the error is in using that syntax, and what would be the correct way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42579853/how-do-i-write-this-require-as-an-es6-import-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your ES5 to this:

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js');
const your_var = mailgun({
  apiKey: config.mail.api.api_key,
  domain: config.mail.api.domain
});
```

In ES6, this would be:

```
import mailgun from 'mailgun-js';
const your_var = mailgun({
  apiKey: config.mail.api.api_key,
  domain: config.mail.api.domain
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The previous code is doing this:

1. Requiring `mailgun-js`
2. Calling the result as a function, passing in some config
3. Taking the result of that as `mailgun`

To do the same in ES6, if we assume that the function is the default export, first we import the function, then we call it:

```
import mailgunFactory from 'mailgun-js';
const mailgun = mailgunFactory({
  apiKey: config.mail.api.api_key,
  domain: config.mail.api.domain
});
```